# Displaying 'No Data found' when there is no data, i.e., Null or undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a table where it shows list of employee Information in a table having few columns, I want to display 'No Data found', in a single row when there is no data coming from the server in angular 6

Comment: show some code, how do you display your data in table

Comment: `<tbody>
<tr>
<td>{{location.name}}</td>
<td>{{location.id}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngIf="location">
   <td>{{location.name}}</td>
   <td>{{location.id}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf="!location">
   <td colspan="2">No Data found</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `colspan` :

```
 <tr *ngIf="list.length == 0">
  <td colspan="number_of_columns_in_header"> No record found </th>
 </tr>
```